# c++ compound assignment when multiplying

Tags: c++

Is there a way of using the compound assignment operator to achieve something like this:

```
a = (a * 10) + b;
```

Initially I tried the following:

```
a *= 10 + b;
```

but this is equivalent to:

```
a = a * (10 + b)
```

Just curious.  Ran across this today.  This is not homework.

Comment: Simply no. The right hand side gets reduced to an expression before assignment occurs.

Comment: Are 'a' and 'b' your own types or a primitive c++ types?

Comment: @arasmussen `a` and `b` are integers in my case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really need to make sure `a` is evaluated only once, you could use the fact that `*=` returns lvalue:

```
(a *= 10) += b;
```

but it's hardly good code, and I think it might be invoking undefined behaviour prior to C++11 due to modifying `a` twice (once in *= and once in +=) without intervening sequence points.

Comment: @EdHeal I'm not.  This was purely because I was interested if you could do it or not.

Comment: I doubt that *`'a' is evaluated only once`*

Comment: I at first thought: Is there really a good chance for UB in compilers before C++11? I took me a while to find http://stackoverflow.com/a/10654019/2932052

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/WWudo

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
        int a = 5;
        int b = 10;
        (a *= b) += 10;
        cout << a;
        return 0;
}
```

Outputs 60.