# Isn't a[i++] = 1 (one) where, computation of the increment to be unsequenced relative to the indexing of the array, leading to violation of S6.5.2

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Word limit on question length..

As pointed out by [@Karl Knechtel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/523612/karl-knechtel,) I am confused that isn't fetching the operation of the array indexing unsequenced relative to the `i++` increment operation? If they are unsequenced, why the C Standard 6.5.2 line mentioning about (emphasis added to the words/phrase which i understand, applies here)

> If a **side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced** **relative** to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or **a value computation using the value of the same scalar object**, the
> behavior is undefined.

I read this question [I can not understand some sentences in C99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033354/i-can-not-understand-some-sentences-in-c99/19033594#19033594) wherein the OP tries to understand why `a[i++] = 1` is undefined. Accepted and one of the highest voted answers by [Pascal Cuoq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139746/pascal-cuoq) mentions that this is defined behavior.

I also tried compiling the program using the `-std=c99`, `-Wall` and `-Wextra` flag and a slew of other flags (basically all the flags which are enabled in GCC 11.2.0), but the code **didn't throw any warning**.

However, my question/confusion is why is this a defined behaviour?

From the [C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p2) S6.5.2

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the
> behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an
> expression, the behaviour is undefined if such an unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the
> orderings.

my understanding/reasoning after reading through most of the threads on SO (with Tags `[C]` and `[sequence-points]`) is that i++ would result in a side effect of updating the value of i. in that case this side-effect is unsequenced to the value computation using the same scaler object. I understand that `a[integer object]` constitutes `value computation`. Then, it should be undefined behavior?

Even from the C99 S6.5(p2)

> Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.

I understand/construe that this expression should also render `a[i++] = 1` undefined?

Comment: If you really read the C standard, you should find that for postfix ++, ["The value computation of the result is sequenced before the side effect of updating the stored value of the operand."](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.4p2) I don't understand why you think that the side effect is unsequenced to the value computation.

Comment: Re “my understanding/reasoning after reading through most of the threads on SO”: To know what the C standard says, read the C standard first.

Comment: "in that case this side-effect is unsequenced to the value computation using the same scaler object." No, that doesn't follow. Some computations using the same object can be sequenced. "I understand that a[integer object] constitutes value computation" And that computation is sequenced relative to the increment - it's not possible to index into `a` until *after* the index has been calculated. The reason `a[i++] = i` is undefined is because the right-hand side still has to be evaluated, even if it's just a variable by itself, and that evaluation isn't sequenced relative to `i++`.

Comment: @cpplearner I think OP expects the computation of the increment to be unsequenced relative to *the indexing of the array*.

Comment: If the side-effect of storing the incremented value was un-sequenced with reading the prior value then `i++` is undefined let alone `a[i++]=1`. But those sentences @cpplearner mention the relative sequence relating to that scalar value (i) is defined. What isn't defined is relative to other calculations like determining the l-value a[i] and storing 1 in it.  But it talks about side-effects on a scalar object itself. Not other side-effects on other scalar objects.

Comment: I wonder if everyone is confusing the 1 (one) with the i (letter I).

Comment: @Braiam, I intend it to be 1 (one)

Comment: Singh, For clarity, 1) it would have been better to use variable names and constants that do not look like each other - too late now. 2)  Synchronize the title with the internal question "why is this a defined behaviour?"

Comment: Where do you see anything unsequenced in the code example?

Comment: @Braiam let me try to breakdown, the expression, a[i++] = 1; into sub-steps.. `temp1=i; 
   temp2=temp1+1;    i=temp2;` my confusion is why `a[temp1]` is defined? Doesn't S6.5.2, means that **If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to** either .. or **a value computation using the value of the same scalar object**, the behavior is undefined.     Wouldn't value computation `a[temp1]` using same scaler object `i (english alphabet)`, thus leading to unsequencing of side-effect (i = temp2;)? thus, leading to undefined behavior?

Comment: Why should the compiler care what a[temp1] is? It needs the index value and that has to be calculated before hand. It will simply wait.

Comment: @Singh Notice it talks about side-effect *on* a scalar object. `a[i]` *uses* the value of `i` but it isn't a side-effect on `i`. So it's correct that the side-effect of storing of 1 in `a[temp1]` where temp1 is the prior value of i is un-sequenced with the storing of i++ it's not a side-effect *on* i itself. C doesn't prescribe a total order of evaluation and side-effects. Whether a[temp1] is stored before or after, in parallel or interleaved with storing temp1+1 to i is undefined by C and may be any or all of those in different executions.

Answer (score 5):

> in that case this side-effect is unsequenced to the value computation using the same scaler object.

The scalar object involved in `i++` is `i`. The side effect of updating `i` is not unsequenced relative to the computation of the value of `i++` because C 2018 6.5.2.4 (which specifies behavior of postfix increment and decrement operators) paragraph 2 says:

> … The value computation of the result is sequenced before the side effect of updating the stored value of the operand…

C 2011 has the same wording. (C 2018 contains only technical corrections and clarifications to C 2011.)

> Even from the C99 S6.5(p2)
>
> > Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.

A rule in the C 1999 standards has no application to the 2011 or 2018 standards; it must be interpreted separately. Between 1999 and 2011, the standard moved from solitary sequence points to finer rules about sequencing relationships.

In `i++`, the prior value is read to determine what the new value of `i` should be, so it conforms to that rule.

The rule was an attempt to say that any reads of a scalar object had to be in the prerequisite chain of an writes of the object. For example, in `i = 3*i + i*i`, all three reads of `i` are necessary to compute the value to be written to `i`, so they are necessarily performed before the write. But in `i = ++i + i;`, the read of `i` for that last term is not a prerequisite for writing to `i` for the `++i`, so it is not necessarily performed before the write. Thus, it would not conform to the rule.

> … I am confused that isn't fetching the operation of the array indexing unsequenced relative to the `i++` increment operation?

The read of the array element is unsequenced relative to the update of `i`, and that is okay because there is no rule that requires it to be sequenced. C 2018 6.5 2 says, emphasis added:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the **same** scalar object or a value computation using the value of the **same** scalar object, the behavior is undefined.

The array element is a different scalar object from `i`, so we do not care that there is no sequencing between the read of the array element and the update to `i`.

Comment: Could you please reply on what Karl Knechtel mentioned in his comment? I am sorry for unintentionally misrepresenting my question. Comment by @Karl is what is my core confusion?

Comment: I don't see in your answer mentioning the 1, but just focusing in the i. The code is element of array equals 1.

Comment: @Braiam: The `1` is not a scalar object and has no bearing on the question.

Comment: Except it does: "wherein the OP tries to understand why `a[i++] = 1` is undefined. Accepted and one of the highest voted answers by Pascal Cuoq mentions that this is defined behavior." That's correct. `a[i++] = 1` is defined. `= i` is undefined, but the question doesn't mention it. Otherwise, maybe we should replace i and 1 for j to force everything to be coherent.

Comment: @Braiam: OP’s question about whether `a[i++] = 1` is defined or undefined has nothing to do with the `1`. It is expressed here: “… i++ would result in a side effect of updating the value of i. in that case this side-effect is unsequenced to the value computation using the same scaler object…” Thus we see the question is about the value computation of `i++` and the side effect of `i++`. The `1` is not involved. Their question may have come from something where `= 1` versus `= i` was at issue, but it is not at issue in this derivative question.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot for the immediate responses from members. I would try to attempt an answer in the language, which, I understood.

After reading a suggestion to read this article [use of abstract tree to tackle sequence point problem](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n926.htm) (I know, it's not normative)

Let me represent a[i++] =1 using the abstract syntax tree.

[image: Abstract tree representation of the expression a[i++] = 1;]

[image]

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).