# Is array[i] = i++ covered by the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, standards

I had a person claiming that this line is not covered by the C++ standard:

```
int i(1);
array_of_int[i] = i++;
```

The person said that it will assign `1` but we cannot know whether it will be in `array_of_int[1]` or `array_of_int[2]` although visual studio and most of compilers will be in `array_of_int[1]`.

Is he correct ?

Comment: As I understand it, this behavior is determined by the compiler and not explicitly addressed in the C++ standard

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc - this is covered in one of the answers.

Comment: Please close or remove my question if it is a dupe, I tried to find it was asked but did not formulate my search with the correct keywords.

Comment: There was something asked a day or two ago that was very similar and featured a test case almost exactly like this. I think it was something like "Is the result 0, 1, or undefined?"

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4177063/947836) in particular explains this very nicely.

Comment: See for an explanation of why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/367690/14065

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is undefined behavior. Literally any behavior is legal.

The passage that forbids that line of code is this:

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored

There is no sequence point between `a[i]` and `i++` and the read to `i` in `a[i]` is not for the purpose of determining what value is stored in `i` by `i++`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I added a link to the wiki page of sequence points

Comment: sequence points have been removed from C++ and replaced with sequencing relationships between statements/sub-expressions. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10655884/365496). This changes some instances of undefined behavior to well-defined behavior, but not in this particular case case.