# Using the result of compound assignment as an lvalue

Tags: c++, c, rvalue, compound-assignment

I'm surprised that this works:

```
double x = 3;
double y = 2;

(x *= 2) += y;
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

The result is 8, which is what it looks like the programmer is trying to achieve.  But I thought assignment operators returned an rvalue - how is it that you can assign to the result of one?

Comment: Related: [What's the result of += in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653903/whats-the-result-of-in-c-and-c/10654019#10654019).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment operators for the built in types return an lvalue
in C++ (unlike in C).  But you cannot use it to modify the
object without an intervening sequence point, so your example is
undefined behavior (in C++03—C++11 changed a lot here, and
I seem to remember that one of the results made your code
defined).

Regardless of the situation with regards to undefined behavior,
you would be better off writing:

```
x = 2 * x + y;
```

It's far more readable.  The fact that the assignment operators
result in lvalues is really only usable when the results are
bound immediately to a reference:

```
T&
SomeClass::f()
{
    //  ...
    return aTinSomeClass += 42;
}
```

And even then, I'd write it in two statements.

(The general rule in C++ is that if the result of an operator
corresponds to the value of an object in memory, then it is an
lvalue.  There was no general rule in C.)

Comment: I certainly agree that your version is more readable - I'm going over someone else's (old) code and this is only one of the... curiosities it has thrown up.  Can you expand on the sequence point a bit?  Perhaps with a reference to the standard for "you cannot use it to modify the object without an intervening sequence point"?

Comment: The reference in pre C++11 is paragraph 4 of section 5: "Between the previous and next sequence point a scalar object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression."  Sequence points are the end of a full expression, calling or returning from a function, and a very few operators: `&&`, `||`, `?:` and the comma operator (but not a comma used e.g. to separate function arguments).

Comment: Thanks.  Curious that `g++ -Wsequence-point` doesn't complain about this (g++ 4.6.3).

Comment: @Tom: In C++11, the behaviour is defined: 5.17/1 says "the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression". But I agree that you should stick with the readable version.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yes.  I had some sort of vague remembrance that C++11 made it defined.  My comments with regards to undefined behavior are based on C++03; I've not really had time to study all of the implications on the new specification (which extend to cover multithreaded access).

Answer (score 0):

In C++, compound assignment operators return lvalues, as per §5.17/1:

> The assignment operator (`=`) and the compound assignment operators all group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand.

In this case, the use of `*=` returns an lvalue denoting the object `x` which is then used as the left operand of the `+=` operator.

Perhaps you are thinking of the simple arithmetic operators like `+` and `*` which do return rvalues.

In C, these operators don't return lvalues and therefore the result can't be further assigned.

Comment: Or perhaps he was thinking of C.

Comment: @JamesKanze Aw, I hate finding out the question was also tagged as C after I've written an answer.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue here.  Tagged or not, his code uses `std::cout`, so we're really only concerned with C++.  But if he did learn C first, he may be just assuming that the rules are the same as in C.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ the result of the assignment operators, including the compound assignment operators (such as `*=`) are l-values, and thus assignables.

In C they are r-values, so your code invalid C code.