# How is this getting evaluated?

Tags: c++

I am feeling very stupid to asking this question. but cant figure out the reason on my own.

```
int main()
{
    int target;
    int buffer =10;
    const int source = 15;
    target = (buffer+=source) = 20;
    cout << target+buffer;
    return 0;
}
```

`target = (buffer+=source) = 20;` will become `target = (25) = 20`.

But if I am giving same statement in my source file, it is giving l-value error.

How the value of `target+buffer` is printing 40.

Comment: Stepping through with a debugger would help you here.

Comment: You are not [trying to compile this with a C compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10654019/335858), are you?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is would be undefined behaviour due to sequencing.

Comment: @Bathsheba aren't parentheses enough to ensure the proper sequencing?

Comment: @Dariusz No, parentheses only ensure associativity.

Comment: According to the C++ standard your problem is undefined behavior because of missing sequence points but the real problem is just that you tried to be clever (always dangerous when programming) and tried to stuff too much in one line. Don't do that. It makes your code unreadable.

Comment: @Sarien that's why the [Keep it Simple, Stupid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) should always be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Some predefined operators, such as +=, require an operand to be an
>   lvalue when applied to basic types [§13.5/7]

`buffer+=source` returns a lvalue reference to `buffer`. **So you have not compile error.**

your statement *can* be evaluate as:

```
buffer+=source;
buffer=20;
target=20;
```

But modifying `buffer` twice in a statement is ***undefined behavior*** and another compiler can evaluate something else as result. *(Not sure in this case also!)*

Comment: @jrok: Thanks, I didn't notice that at first. Edited.

Comment: Don't thank me too soon, I'm actualy not sure anymore. :) *"In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value
computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression.* I'm pretty sure it was undefined in C++03, but this quote is from C++11.

Comment: @jrok: So you can ask a great question in SO about that and you have my +1 for that :-)