# pre-increment and post- increment

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    ++a = 20;      
    printf("a = %d", a);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The output obtained for the above code is : a=20; when run as C++ code.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    a++ = 20;      
    printf("a = %d", a);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This gives compilation error. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: `++a = 20;` will not compile.which compiler using?

Comment: The actual error message is "compilation error"? That sounds like a bug -- the compiler should have given a clear indication of what is wrong here. What compiler are you using? Try another, for a more expansive error message.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer to a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10654019/335858).

Answer (score 6):

You are compiling your program with a C++ compiler.

In C++, the result of pre-increment operator is a lvalue but the result of post-increment operator is not a lvalue.

In C, both pre-increment and post-increment operators are not lvalues so you cannot assign to the result of an increment operator.

As you can see C and C++ have different rules int this matter which is not surprising as they are different languages.

Comment: +1 for C and C++ are different languages, and spelling out how it shows here.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `++a = 20` or `a++ = 20` is wrong and any good compiler would give errors. If you understand the `C` philosophy, `a++` or `++a` is `a = a+1`. So, `++a = 20` practically means
    a = a+1 = 20
which is ridiculous. These statements are to be used alone as shortcut to increment. Please go through Ritchie and Kernighan's classic book on the `C` language.

I assume that you are using `C` compiler